# Generate a maze of with no checkboard - Eller's Method / Recursive BackTracking with pair columns / lines

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to create maze with a recursive backtracking algorithm / eller's method with pair columns and pair lines.
There's a problem, if the columns / lines are pair.
For instance if I have a map of 4*4 :

```
X***
****
****
***X
```

The up left corner is the beginning, the other the end. Basically, I can't create a sort of "checkboard" as with a 5*5 maze (or any odd number I think).

```
X|X|X
-----
X|X|X
-----
X|X|X
```

Because it would do for a 4*4:

```
X|X|
----
X|X|
----
```

(Knowing that I have to reach the bottom right corner from the top left one).
Does algorithms exist with this paterne or do I have to find a way to include these paterne with recursive backtracking  / eller's method.

Also, the width of the path can be more than 1 unit.

Example for a 12 * 4 :
`* = empty cells`
`X = walls`

```
1*XXXX****XX
X****X*X**XX
X*XX***XX***
X*XXXX***XX2
```

Entry is 1, exit 2

Another example for a 4*4 :

```
1*XX
X**X
***X
XX*2
```

Entry point and exit are always the same and the width of the path can be one or more, it does not matter.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data structure requires that grid cells are used for walls, then indeed you must make sure that the width and height of your grid are odd. If you have a recursive process, then you have to make sure that the subgrids also have this property (odd number of rows and columns). Two adjacent subgrids need to *share* one column or one row. So make sure you correctly divide the grid for the recursive process.

If for example you want to apply [the iterative Eller's algorithm](https://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2010/12/29/maze-generation-eller-s-algorithm) to potentially generate the following example:

```
1*XXXX****XX
X****X*X**XX
X*XX***XX***
X*XXXX***XX2
```

Then you need to see each character as a cell (also the X cells), not as a wall. The walls are *between* the cells. So you can picture the above grid in the following "syntax":

```
┌───────┬───────────────┬───────────────┬───────┐
│ 1     │ x   x   x   x │               │ x   x │
├───┐   └───────────┐   │   ┌───┐       │       │
│ x │               │ x │   │ x │       │ x   x │
│   │   ┌───────┐   └───┘   │   └───┐   └───────┤
│ x │   │ x   x │           │ x   x │           │
│   │   │       └───────┐   └───────┼───────┐   │
│ x │   │ x   x   x   x │           │ x   x │ 2 │
└───┴───┴───────────────┴───────────┴───────┴───┘
```

So here the areas with "x" are not really walls -- they are enclosures that are unreachable. This would not happen with the above referenced algorithm, because of the steps that say:

> add at least one vertical connection

...and:

> ... the last row. This time, we must connect ALL adjacent (but disjoint) cells

If you omit these requirements, such enclosures could be created. The walls in this syntax (used by the referenced algorithm) are separations (lines) which are either horizontal or vertical. They don't translate *themselves* to "X" in your notation.

Comment: Is there an algorithm that would work with even numbers ? Considering that a box can be a part of the path or a wall ? Can't find anything about that on internet.

Comment: You can't find it because usually this is treated as a graph problem, where all nodes are reachable cells, and he absence of an edge means there is a wall. In your data structure, you should just add a dummy row and/or column to make it odd. You should add it at the side where walls are missing.

Comment: This maze cannot be find with those kind of algorithms thus ? (* = empty cells : X = walls)
See pastebin below

Comment: Sorry I cannot read that.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xBkLMsnu should be more readable - it's a 24*6 maze

Comment: I don't understand that notation: you have spaces, X, and *. I would expect only a binary grid, not with 3 possible characters.

Comment: Sorry there has been an error, only * and X are valid ^^"

Comment: That looks like a different data structure than I thought you were asking about. Can you edit your question and give a few well-structured examples (but not as big), also indicating what the entry point is and the exit point. Please also provide the algorithm you are using. I looked for Eller's, but it was not recursive.

Comment: It's done ! example above

Comment: Can you also quote or give the algorithm you are referring to? I am now thinking you are using an implementation that was designed for a different data structure (where rows and columns are always odd, as I wrongly assumed was also your original grid). Note how in the first part of your question, you use pipe and hyphen symbols, which are typical for the odd-sized grid systems. But your final example deviates from that approach.

Comment: An algorithm is the thing I'm looking for, anything that would create a maze as the first (24*6). The maps quoted above are just some random maps created with no algorithm but they are valid. Columns and rows can be even or odd or both. I could create "artificial" walls if columns / rows are even + a known algorithm (eller's one or recursive) but for odd numbers, I don't know.

Comment: Oh, so you don't actually have implemented anything? Hmm... why not start. There are many resources online, like [here](https://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2010/12/29/maze-generation-eller-s-algorithm). If you have a problem after implementing that, then maybe ask about that?

Comment: That's the link I was on, but it only works if the columns / rows are even. What if one of the two is odd ? As said above, a wall is part of the map's size.

Comment: As far as I can see there is no requirement to have odd rows (it works with one row at a time, for any number of rows) or odd columns (it just creates sets for connected cells, no matter what the number of columns is). In your last example, you would have to see the X cells as areas that are also cells, but which are bounded by divisors, like in the linked algorithm.

Comment: On their example, the grid is not part of the map's size. There's 5 cells but with the grid, it creates a 9 width maze. With 4 cells the size would still be even including the grid

Comment: See addition to answer. This is all comes down to the fact that there are different notations for mazes, and you use a different one than the referenced algorithm. You must translate it.

Comment: I'll look into this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to use the recursive backtracking algorithm because it is more optimised to create a maze as in C (the langage I used to create a maze). Using the Eller's method, I should've create an integer array then switch to a char array.

To solve the issue with pair columns / rows, here is the trick.

Let's assume that I have a 4*4 maze (including walls). Thus, at the beginning it will render as

```
XXXX                                                 1XXX
XXXX                                                 XXXX
XXXX -> Let's add the entry point (1) + exit (2) ->  XXXX
XXXX                                                 XXX2
```

We haven't defined the walls at the moment, as they account for a cell in our case.
What we will do is "set" the walls every two rows beginning at first.

```
1|X|
---- --> - and | are walls
X|X|
---2
```

We can now use the recursive backtracking algorithm, except we will advance every time of two cells instead of one. However, as the exit point is considered as a wall, you will never reach the exit. Just set randomly at the beginning of your algorithm an empty cell up to the exit or on the left of it.

```
1XXX       1XXX
XXXX       XXXX
XXX*  OR   XXXX  --> * = empty cells (reachable in the maze)
XXX2       XX*2
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).